# Testing an async injectable service

Tags: angular, unit-testing, asynchronous, ionic2, jasmine

I'm trying to set up tests of my `@Injectable` storage service.

```
@Injectable()
export class StorageService {...

constructor(private platform: Platform,
  public instanceService: InstanceService,
  private logger: LoggingService,
  private database: SQLite = null) {... //injecting a db mock
```

I've created several versions of the test that succeed, but I've learned they only succeed because they are async and are misreporting the error.

Here's the setup.

```
describe('Storage Service tests', () => {
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [],
        providers: [
            StorageService,
            { provide: Platform, useClass: PlatformMock },
            { provide: InstanceService, useClass: InstanceServiceMock },
            { provide: LoggingService, useClass: LoggingServiceMock },
            { provide: ConfigurationService, useClass: ConfigurationServiceMock },
            { provide: SQLite, useClass: DBMock },
            MockBackend,
            BaseRequestOptions,
            {
                provide: Http,
                useFactory: (mockBackend, options) => {
                    return new Http(mockBackend, options);
                },
                deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
            }
        ],
        imports: [
            HttpModule
        ]
    }).compileComponents();
}));
```

Here I'm trying to test `setFailedImageUpdate`

I'm struggling to know how to both *inject* the service so it initializes *and* pass in `done` for the async completion.

```
it('should set failed image', (done) => {
    let cu = new UnsavedImageUpdate();

    inject([StorageService, MockBackend], (storageService, mockBackend) => {
        storageService.db = new DBMock();
        storageService.setFailedImageUpdate([cu]).then((res) => {
            expect(res).toEqual("1234");
            done();
        })();
    })
});
```

The error I'm getting on this iteration is:

```
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout
specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
```

How can I set up my test to both inject `StorageService` **and** pass in `done`?

EDIT: Trying to follow @learner's suggestions, I created this:

```
it('should set failed image', async() => {
    let cu = new UnsavedImageUpdate();
    var storageService = TestBed.get(StorageService);
    storageService.db = new DBMock();
    storageService.setFailedImageUpdate([cu]).then((res) => {
        expect(res).toEqual("1234");
    })
});
```

The test succeeds, but when I debug into it, I got this error:

```
'expect' was used when there was no current spec, 
this could be because an asynchronous test timed out
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `inject`, you can get the injected service in your test method using `TestBed.get(StorageService)` and you can use `async` function from angular testing module which waits for the async operation to complete instead of using `done`.

Use done like this:

```
it('should set failed image', (done) => {
    let cu = new UnsavedImageUpdate();
    var storageService = TestBed.get(StorageService);
    storageService.db = new DBMock();
    storageService.setFailedImageUpdate([cu]).then((res) => {
        expect(res).toEqual("1234");
        done();
    })
});
```

Comment: Can you mock up a sample?

Comment: That got it!  Thank you!!

Comment: I'd love to see a version w/o done, if you wanted to give it a shot.

Comment: I would want to see the implementation of 'setFailedImageUpdate' to use 'async' in test.